# How to request a third-party login within a seperate mobile application

Tags: login, copywriting, mobile-web, authentication

I'm designing a mobile app that requires the user to log-in with their LinkedIn account.
I feel I might have cluttered too much info into it, but everything seems to be important.

[image: Log-in pop-up (ignore the yellow numbers, they're links to annotations]

I want the user to understand that:

1. This is NOT LinkedIn.
2. We cannot show her search results if she doesn't log-in.
3. We don't keep her username and password (she enters them on LinkedIn's permissions dialogue, much like when you connect with your Facebook account)
4. She will only have to do this once.
5. If she doesn't have a LinkedIn account, she could register.
6. If she doesn't want to give us permissions, she could go to LinkedIn directly, but she'll have to redo her search there.

I also can't change the button (it's mandatory according to LinkedIn's API rules).

**Is this too cluttered? If you think it is, do you have any idea how to redesign this to be more usable and look better?**

Comment: Is this an additional feature of your app - or is that what the app is for?

Comment: I've slightly edited your question because it comes across as too localised to your own application. This change should mean it's useful to more readers than just yourself.

Comment: Hi Adriaan. Searching Linkedin is the core functionality of this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using way to much text. The great example Adriann gave explains a great deal just via the graphics. Don't feel you have to explain every little thing... users are much more sophisticated than we think sometimes. Clearly if this becomes an issue it will be obvious when you user test... but start with simple and then build in complexity as you need it.
Don't use words like "unofficial" makes you sound dodgy (:

If you have a good logo it will show that you are your own company. I love the "Powered by the Linked in API" shown in the example.

You are definitely providing too many options. Number 3 should go. Number 2 should just be presented subtly.

If you really can't change the button you can do something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr4iGN.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You could remove the third step completely, unless you have some way that the user will be able to come back to your app once they've finished on LinkedIn.

Though I understand your app is not LinkedIn itself, you are still using the API from LinkedIn so you are still using their services.

Have a look at the example below:

1. Introduction gives context by using the word 'profile'
2. Powered by gives credibility and re-enforces that this app isn't LinkedIn, but rather using LinkedIn's engine.
3. The way LinkedIn is brought in near the bottom at the 'Forgot your password?' link is brilliant and again - reaffirms that this app is not LinkedIn.

Hope that gives you some input.

[image]

LunchMeet http://lunchmeetapp.com/

Comment: I think you should have kept the green tick on this one... my answer completely fed off your example.. its already been useful in another context today. Thanks.