# Combining Login and Forgot PIN in a mobile interface

Tags: gui-design, mobile, login

This question is for an interface used on Mobile Phones, specifically for logging in to Mobile websites with the MSISDN of the user.

Currently the local version of the interface in question looks like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLzsJ6.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

In the above sketch the *120*12345# string represents a USSD code presented to the visitor as a clickable link. This dials the USSD code and allows the customer to retrieve his PIN code.

I am localizing this application with the aim of deploying to a country that does not support USSD.

Would it be advisable to combine the PIN retrieval mechanism into this one interface, or should I have a separate page for inputting MSISDN that will send you the PIN?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to have a separate page for the forgot pin page due to two reasons:

1. You are designing for mobile, so there's not a lot of space to use and you want to keep the design as simple as possible. Making the design simpler will enable users to see the *forgot pin* link easily.
2. My assumption is that the majority of your users will not be using *forgot pin* so you keep it on it's own page. It's also not too much effort on the users that do need to use it to access it this way.

Not exactly the same but have a look at this screenshot of a mobile interface where, in this case, the *forgot password* link is elegantly shown right at the bottom of the page clearly written in an understandable way. https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/22148/7493

I really like your thinking of having the number that they would have to sms or dial as a link to make it very easy to just press it, so I would try and keep this thinking on that page, if you do choose to have the *forgot pin* on a separate page.